# What is the correct usage of ORMLite with ASPNET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ormlite-servicestack

Reading the documentation for ORMLite, it says to register the Connection Factory as a singleton if you're using an IoC container.

Is this the correct syntax for that with ASPNET Core 2.0? Or should I be using the .addDBContext method?

```
        var dbConnectString = Configuration["DBConnectString"];

        var userName = Configuration["DBUserId"];
        dbConnectString = dbConnectString.Replace("{your_username}", $"\'{userName}\'");

        var password = Configuration["DBPassword"];
        dbConnectString = dbConnectString.Replace("{your_password}", $"\'{password}\'");

        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(dbConnectString,SqlServerDialect.Provider);

        services.AddSingleton(dbFactory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddDbContext` is used for Entity Framework Core. Don't use that guy if you aren't using EF.

My method is as follows:

- `services.AddSingleton(IDbConnectionFactory)` in the `Startup` class. Example: https://github.com/afmorris/MorrisPhotos/blob/master/MorrisPhotos.Web/Startup.cs#L25
- If you use data access in your controller methods, make the controller inherit from `ServiceStackController`. Example: https://github.com/afmorris/MorrisPhotos/blob/master/MorrisPhotos.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L15
- Access the `IDbConnection` via the `Db` property in your controller. Example: https://github.com/afmorris/MorrisPhotos/blob/master/MorrisPhotos.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L26